# updating dll file gives access denied / error 5

Tags: inno-setup

My setupper gives the ERROR access denied dialog when overwriting one DLL fails,
its locked&in use sometimes.

what is recommended procedure for doing this..

Can I somehow make INNO to compare if its even necessary to overwrite this DLL (size match?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoSetup automatically compares the files to see if it needs to be replaced by looking at the version resource in the file.

You should add the RestartReplace flag to the [Files] entry for your DLL (and any other file that might be in memory / locked).  From the InnoSetup documentation:

> restartreplace
>
> When an existing file needs to be
>   replaced, and it is in use (locked) by
>   another running process, Setup will by
>   default display an error message. This
>   flag tells Setup to instead register
>   the file to be replaced the next time
>   the system is restarted (by calling
>   MoveFileEx or by creating an entry in
>   WININIT.INI). When this happens, the
>   user will be prompted to restart their
>   computer at the end of the
>   installation process.
>
> To maintain compatibility with Windows
>   95/98/Me, long filenames should not be
>   used on entries with this flag. Only
>   "8.3" filenames are supported.
>   (Windows NT platforms do not have this
>   limitation.)
>
> NOTE: This flag has no effect on
>   Windows NT platforms if the user does
>   not have administrative privileges.
>   Therefore, when using this flag, it is
>   recommended that you leave the
>   PrivilegesRequired [Setup] section
>   directive at the default setting of
>   admin.

Comment: it seems inno cannot compare when DLL is in use?

Comment: Actually, I think it compares the file before attempting to replace it.  When it attempts to replace it and finds it locked, the error is returned.  Make sure your DLL has a version resource in it and the new version has a higher version than the old one.